# I don't understand the example of closure for loop error from mdn

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

**1.MDN example**

The code snippet below assign a function that display the help text to each text field when focus, here is the link to JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7gjv/8164/

```
function showHelp(help) {
          document.getElementById('help').textContent = help;
        }
        
        function setupHelp() {
          var helpText = [
              {'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address'},
              {'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name'},
              {'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)'}
            ];
        
          for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
            var item = helpText[i];
            document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
              showHelp(item.help);
            }
          }
        }
        
        setupHelp();
```

But it will only display the last help text no matter which of the three input is focused. MDN says the function assigned to all three inputs is a closure, so they share the same reference to variable helpText, when the loop's over, i=2, so all three input have reference to the last item in helpText.

**2.My test**

The part where i dont understand is why all three inputs have the same reference to the same variable item
I make a test like this

```js
(function() {
  function closure() {
    var i = 0;
    return {
      display: function() {
        console.log(i);
      },
      add: function() {
        i += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  var a = closure();
  var b = closure();

  a.add();
  a.display(); //return 1
  b.display(); //return 0 
})()
```

**3.My thoughts and questions**

From the test, a and b have different i variables, i from a changed but b remain the same.
But in the for loop, all inputs point to the same variable, thus the for loop change the value i causing all inputs point to the last item in helpText

So my question is why do they points to the same variable but in my test a,b don't.

Comment: *"but in my test a,b don't"* Because `i` is defined *inside* the function, but in the MDN example, `item` is defined *outside* of the event handler.

Comment: I dont really get it, i comprehend that onfocus is one of the element properties {...,onfocus:function(){}} is that right ?

Comment: Yes, the function is assigned to a property, but that's not really important. What's important is: The function accesses a *free variable* (a variable not defined in itself) and the function is called *after* the loop terminates. You'd achieve the same behavior if you moved the `var i = 0;` declaration outside the `closure` function.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're declaring the variable `i` inside the `closure` method. When you are calling `closure` a second time, a new `i` variable is created in the scope of that specific function execution, and the returned object is bound to that variable.

Try moving the variable declaration outside of the `closure` function and you will see that the result is the same as the MDN example.

Comment: Now i think about it, a function access a global variable is a pretty basic feature, it just that other language cannot assign function like javascript

Comment: @khuongduy354: There are actually a lot of languages where functions are *first-class objects*. But even in those languages, closures might work differently.